# Positioning a label above a brace

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to position `22` in the "appropriate" position above the brace. Using a node to associate a number with a brace does not put the number at the cusp in the brace by default.  Why is that?!

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,angles,positioning,intersections,quotes,decorations.markings,backgrounds,patterns}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}



\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

%A is the vertex of an angle of 55 degrees; the sides of this angle are AB
%and AC. $AB = 22$ and $AC = 13$.
\coordinate (A) at (0,0);
\node (vertex_A) at ($(A) + (82.5:7.5pt)$){$A$};
\coordinate (B) at (235:5.5);
\node (vertex_B) at ($(B) + (225:7.5pt)$){$B$};
\coordinate (C) at (290:3.25);
\node (vertex_C) at ($(C) + (-45:7.5pt)$){$C$};
\draw[name path=AB] (A) -- (B);
\draw[name path=AC] (A) -- (C);
\draw[name path=BC] (B) -- (C);

\path pic[draw, angle radius=5mm,"$\scriptstyle{55}$",angle eccentricity=1.5] {angle = B--A--C};

%These commands label the length of AC.
\coordinate (AC_midpoint) at ($(A)!0.5!(C)$);
\node (AC_midpoint_label) at ($(AC_midpoint) + (20:7.5pt)$) {$\scriptstyle{13}$};


%These commands put a brace above line segment AB and label the length `22`.  First, coordinates A' and B' are defined to be 2.5pt from AB. A brace is drawn between A' and B'. In this way, the label for the length of AB is put in the center of the brace by default.
\coordinate (A') at ($(A)!2.5pt!-90:(B)$);
\coordinate (B') at ($(B)!2.5pt!90:(A)$);
\draw[decorate,decoration={brace,amplitude=5pt}] (B') -- node[fill=white, inner sep=1pt]{$\scriptstyle{22}$} (A');

%These commands draw the altitude of the triangle from C. The foot of the altitude is
%labeled P. The length of the altitude is labeled h.
\coordinate (P) at ($(A)!(C)!(B)$);
\draw[dashed] (C) -- (P);
\coordinate (PC_midpoint) at ($(P)!0.5!(C)$);
\node (PC_midpoint_label) at ($(PC_midpoint) + (90:7.5pt)$) {$\scriptstyle{h}$};

%The following commands make the right-angle mark.
\coordinate (U) at ($(P)!4mm!-45:(A)$);
\draw (U) -- ($(P)!(U)!(A)$);
\draw (U) -- ($(P)!(U)!(C)$);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Use `\draw[decorate,decoration={brace,raise=12pt,amplitude=5pt}] 
  (B) -- node[fill=white, inner sep=1pt,above left=7pt and 17pt]{$\scriptstyle 22$} (A);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `raise` moves the `brace` decoration you'll need some manual fine tunning using, for example:

```
node[fill=white, inner sep=1pt,above left=8pt and 16pt] {$\scriptstyle 22$} (A);
```

A complete example:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,angles,positioning,intersections,quotes,decorations.markings,backgrounds,patterns}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
%A is the vertex of an angle of 55 degrees; the sides of this angle are AB
%and AC. $AB = 22$ and $AC = 13$.
\coordinate (A) at (0,0);
\node (vertex_A) at ($(A) + (82.5:7.5pt)$){$A$};
\coordinate (B) at (235:5.5);
\node (vertex_B) at ($(B) + (225:7.5pt)$){$B$};
\coordinate (C) at (290:3.25);
\node (vertex_C) at ($(C) + (-45:7.5pt)$){$C$};
\draw[name path=AB] (A) -- (B);
\draw[name path=AC] (A) -- (C);
\draw[name path=BC] (B) -- (C);

\path pic[draw, angle radius=5mm,"$\scriptstyle{55}$",angle eccentricity=1.5] {angle = B--A--C};

%These commands label the lengths of AB and of AC.
\coordinate (AB_midpoint) at ($(A)!0.5!(B)$);
\draw[decorate,decoration={brace,raise=12pt,amplitude=5pt}] 
  (B) -- node[fill=white, inner sep=1pt,above left=8pt and 16pt]{$\scriptstyle 22$} (A);
\coordinate (AC_midpoint) at ($(A)!0.5!(C)$);
\node (AC_midpoint_label) at ($(AC_midpoint) + (20:7.5pt)$) {$\scriptstyle{13}$};


%These commands draw the altitude of the triangle from C. The foot of the altitude is
%labeled P. The length of the altitude is labeled h.
\coordinate (P) at ($(A)!(C)!(B)$);
\draw[dashed] (C) -- (P);
\coordinate (PC_midpoint) at ($(P)!0.5!(C)$);
\node (PC_midpoint_label) at ($(PC_midpoint) + (90:7.5pt)$) {$\scriptstyle{h}$};

%The following commands make the right-angle mark.
\coordinate (U) at ($(P)!4mm!-45:(A)$);
\draw (U) -- ($(P)!(U)!(A)$);
\draw (U) -- ($(P)!(U)!(C)$);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

### Update

After the edit to the question, `raise` is not used and the brace is drawn using some auxiliary coordinates. However, some manual intervention will still be needed:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,angles,positioning,intersections,quotes,decorations.markings,backgrounds,patterns}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}



\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

%A is the vertex of an angle of 55 degrees; the sides of this angle are AB
%and AC. $AB = 22$ and $AC = 13$.
\coordinate (A) at (0,0);
\node (vertex_A) at ($(A) + (82.5:7.5pt)$){$A$};
\coordinate (B) at (235:5.5);
\node (vertex_B) at ($(B) + (225:7.5pt)$){$B$};
\coordinate (C) at (290:3.25);
\node (vertex_C) at ($(C) + (-45:7.5pt)$){$C$};
\draw[name path=AB] (A) -- (B);
\draw[name path=AC] (A) -- (C);
\draw[name path=BC] (B) -- (C);

\path pic[draw, angle radius=5mm,"$\scriptstyle{55}$",angle eccentricity=1.5] {angle = B--A--C};

%These commands label the length of AC.
\coordinate (AC_midpoint) at ($(A)!0.5!(C)$);
\node (AC_midpoint_label) at ($(AC_midpoint) + (20:7.5pt)$) {$\scriptstyle{13}$};


%These commands put a brace above line segment AB and label the length `22`.  First, coordinates A' and B' are defined to be 2.5pt from AB. A brace is drawn between A' and B'. In this way, the label for the length of AB is put in the center of the brace by default.
\coordinate (A') at ($(A)!2.5pt!-90:(B)$);
\coordinate (B') at ($(B)!2.5pt!90:(A)$);
\draw[decorate,decoration={brace,amplitude=5pt}] 
  (B') -- node[above left=0pt and 3pt]{$\scriptstyle 22$} (A');

%These commands draw the altitude of the triangle from C. The foot of the altitude is
%labeled P. The length of the altitude is labeled h.
\coordinate (P) at ($(A)!(C)!(B)$);
\draw[dashed] (C) -- (P);
\coordinate (PC_midpoint) at ($(P)!0.5!(C)$);
\node (PC_midpoint_label) at ($(PC_midpoint) + (90:7.5pt)$) {$\scriptstyle{h}$};

%The following commands make the right-angle mark.
\coordinate (U) at ($(P)!4mm!-45:(A)$);
\draw (U) -- ($(P)!(U)!(A)$);
\draw (U) -- ($(P)!(U)!(C)$);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks.  I had supposed that a `node` associated with a `\draw` command with an option of `decoration={brace,raise=12pt,amplitude=5pt}` would put the label, by default, in the middle of the brace.

Comment: Here is what would obviate the guessing - replace `(A)` and `(B)` with coordinates that are 12pt above the line segment AB.

Comment: @user74973 Regarding your first comment, that is the behaviour without using `raise`; since you used `raise` the brace moves but the node in the path doesn't and you have to make the manual adjustments. Regarding your second comment, yes, that's another option but then you need to make manual adjustments to the positions of the new coordinates, so in both cases manual intervention is required.

Comment: I removed `\draw[decorate,decoration={brace,raise=12pt,amplitude=5pt}] 
  (B) -- node[fill=white, inner sep=1pt,above left=8pt and 16pt]{$\scriptstyle 22$} (A);` and included the following three commands: `\coordinate (A') at ($(A)!2.5pt!-90:(B)$);`, `\coordinate (B') at ($(B)!2.5pt!90:(A)$);`, and `\draw[decorate,decoration={brace,amplitude=5pt}] (B') -- node[fill=white, inner sep=1pt]{$\scriptstyle{22}$} (A');`.  The label `22` interferes with the brace.

Comment: Would it be more convenient for you if I edit my post?

Comment: @user74973 Yes, I think that adding an edit to the question would be better.

Comment: I just edited it.

Comment: @user74973 PLease see my updated answer.

Comment: I see that you have added the option `above left=0pt and 3pt` to the edited code.  This looks nice.  I suppose that you first tried `above left` and when you saw that the label `22` was still too close, you decided to move it leftward by `3pt`.

Comment: I guess without any specifications about the position of the node, it is put halfway between A' and B'.